# Find the equation of the plane passing through the point and is normal to a plane

Tags: vectors

The question is: Find the equation of the plane passing through the point (2, 1, 3) and is normal to the plane 3x - 7y + 5z = -55.

I tried using the formula r.n = a.n

Doing so, I get:
(x,y,z).(3,-7,5) = (2,1,3).(3,-7,5)

Hence, the equation is, 3x - 7y + 5z = 14.

I'm not sure if this correct because the normal that I found for my equation is parallel to the plane but not perpendicular to it.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the question correctly? Could it be "find the equation of the *line* passing..."? Because (assuming that "normal" for planes means "their normal vectors are orthogonal") the current problem has infinitely many solutions, so "**the** plane passing through the point..." doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, this was the question. That's why I was confused as well

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. Every plane containing $(1,2,3)$ and the orthogonal projection of $(1,2,3)$ onto the given plane is a solution.

Comment: @mfl do you mean (2,1,3)? where did (1,2,3) come from?

Comment: @llamaro25 Yes, sorry. I mean $(2,1,3).$

Comment: @mfl is my working correct? since it has the point (2,1,3) and also the perpendicular

Comment: No. You got a parallel plane and you are asked for one which is normal.

Comment: @mfl i dont quite understand how to solve this. can you help?

Comment: Perhaps the right "solution" is to ask the person who posed the problem whether it was supposed to be "line" rather than "plane", and if it was supposed to be "plane", how you were supposed to choose among the infinitely many correct answers. If it came from a textbook...well, authors make mistakes too. I promise we do. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote by $\alpha:Ax+By+Cz=D$ a plane which solves the question.

The plane contains the point $P(2,1,3).$ So it is $2A+B+3C=D.$

Now, it is perpendicular to the plane $\pi:3x - 7y + 5z = -55.$ So, we have that $(A,B,C)\cdot (3,-7,5)=0.$ That is: $3A-7B+5C=0.$

We get $C=\frac{7B-3A}{5}$ and $D=2A+B+\frac{21B-9A}{5}.$

So the infinitely many solutions are given by

$$Ax+By+\frac{7B-3A}{5}z=2A+B+\frac{21B-9A}{5}$$ where $(A,B)\in \mathbb{R}^2, (A,B)\ne (0,0).$ In other words

$$5Ax+5By+(7B-3A)z=A+26B$$ where $(A,B)\in \mathbb{R}^2, (A,B)\ne (0,0).$

One particular solution ($A=B=1$) is $$5x+5y+4z=27.$$

Comment: I understand this now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Pick a vector on the plan by subtracting two points on the plane. Say $(1,1,\frac{-51}{5})$, $(1,2,\frac{-44}{5})$ and get the vector$(0,1,\frac{7}{5})$ on the plan.
Then equation of a plan normal to the desired plan is $(y-1)+\frac{7}{5}(z-3)=0$.
Is this correct?